# Make li select checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've got a script which checks a checkbox when the `span` of an `li` is clicked. My problem is that the width of the `li` is longer than the `span` and therefore, part of the `li` doesn't check the checkbox.

```js
$('ul.myclass li span').click( function() {
    var $cb = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox");
    if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
        $cb.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $cb.prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

```css
.myclass li span {
  margin-left: 5px;   
}

li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myclass">
    <li><input type="checkbox"><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"><span>some text</span></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"><span>some text</span></li>
</ul>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7w82S/89/

Answer (score 10):

Use the appropriate HTML `<label>` element to associate the text with the `<input>`:

```
<ul class="myclass">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>some text</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>some text</span></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"><span>some text</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

With `display: block;` (for the `<label>` element's style) to fill its ancestor `<li>` and the desired behaviour is automatic, requiring no JavaScript.

Comment: Say I had to have the label after the `input`... would it still require no Javascript?

Comment: For the whole `<li>` to be clickable, with the `<label>` after the check-box (in the HTML) that would require JavaScript. If you could leave the check-box within the `<label>`, but position it before, or after, using CSS then it would still work with the above approach.

Comment: hmm... could i have two `labels` in the `li`?

Comment: You could, so long as they're not nested; but instead of asking further questions in comments why not edit your question to include the desired end result, or the requirements under which you're working? If the HTML has to be in a specific order, or structure, show that. If it's to achieve a specific visual look, or aesthetic, show that (using an image). Currently while I can answer each of your questions as you ask them I'm not sure I'm giving you the best advice without knowing the required end-result.

Answer (score 1):

if i got the question right you can do this

```
$('ul.myclass li').click( function() {
   var $cb = $(this).find(":checkbox");
    if (!$cb.prop("checked")) {
        $cb.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $cb.prop("checked", false);
    }
 });
```